# 1.8 - 2.0 Vout regulator

Tags: batteries, design, zener

I would like suggestions to build a very simple circuit to supply a Vout of 1.8-2.0 V with a Vin of 3 V supplied by 2 D cell batteries. Load is 20 Ω. I think 2.4 V Zener with a regular diode could bring the voltage into range (2.4 V - 0.6 across the diode = 1.8 V.
I'd like Vout to remain constant as Vin decreases as the batteries age.
(obviously I am very far from an electronics design genius)
The output is a 3 ms pulse every 1500 ms so battery life should be good.

Comment: A Zener diode can not be used as a voltage regulator. At most it provides a voltage reference that can be used as part of a voltage regulator.

Comment: How stiff (output impedance) and how efficient does it need to be? The simplest scenario is obviously a single 10 ohm series resistor.

Comment: You won't get the full life of the batteries with a simple linear regulator, maybe 1/2 to 3/4, depending on current profile, the output voltage you choose and the regulator performance. End of life for an alkaline battery is typically taken as 0.8V, so 1.6V for two.

Comment: @asdfex  Who told you that? Zener diodes have been used as shunt regulators since the 1950s. One wouldn't work very well in this particular case, but there are plenty of applications where they make perfectly adequate regulators.

Comment: Battery life will be very bad with Zener regulator as it consumes current constantly despite no load.

Comment: Is the load a 20 ohm resistor?

Comment: @GodJihyo Mz comment may be a bit too general. Yes, you can build shunt resistors, but none of the requirements are met in this application: Low current, large voltage drop with small variations of input voltage, irrelevance of efficiency.  Nothing one should consider today given the price difference to a real regulator.

Comment: For such rating (3/1500) a charge pump can be an effective solution. It can be turned off after output cap gets charged to desired voltage (2V) so will drains almost nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest solution is something like the [LD39015M18R from ST](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/ld39015.pdf), a low voltage, low drop-out linear regulator. It will provide exactly 1.8V at up to 150mA, all the way down to about 2V input. From their datasheet:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzR7Kd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Very nice find.

Comment: Agreed !  Thankyou Simon Fitch

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple LDO regulator that may meet your needs, although of course there are many specific devices that work better, for less than a dollar. But this can be built with any old NPN and PNP transistors.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffiJTr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: Simple LDO 1.8V out with 3.3-1.6V input]

Here is an LTspice simulation of a circuit using a PMOS series device, and the temperature effect at 0, 25, and 50 C.

[image: LDO using PMOS, and temperature effect]

Comment: This answer is great! Proper old-school, cereal box and shoelaces.

Comment: Its main issue is temperature coefficient of -2 mV/C. If Vbe is 650 mV at 25C it will be 600 mV at 50C and 700 mV at 0C. So for a nominal 1.8V output will change about +/- 10% over that range, or 1.98 to 1.62 VDC. A thermistor (or maybe another diode) might be used for compensation. https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/vbe-temperature-coefficient-of-transistors.322302/